# Creating column based on other table's column in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables which is 'table1' and 'table2' , table1 looks like this

| elements |
| --- |
| facebook |
| whatsapp |
| youtube |
| facebook |
| youtube |

and other table table2 looks like this

| id | e |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | youtube |
| 2 | facebook |
| 3 | whatsapp |

i want to make column "e_id" in table1  based on element's "id" in table2

so the result may look like this

| elements | e_id |
| --- | --- |
| facebook | 2 |
| whatsapp | 3 |
| youtube | 1 |
| facebook | 2 |
| youtube | 1 |

the e_id should be dynamic ( like if element is found in the table2, it will assign its id in e_id column )

is there a optimized way to do this in postgreSQL?

Comment: Hi, where is your code ? What have you tried ?

Comment: i am currently using dbt tool, and  i made table2 as a dict and compared with them with  for loop for the column e_id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create column based on other column in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721997/how-to-create-column-based-on-other-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about optimized way but you need to alter your table1 first then you do an update on it. cheers!

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD COLUMN e_id int;

UPDATE table1
SET table1.e_id = table2.id
FROM table2
WHERE table1.elements = table2.e
```